# MySQL PDO Transactions Exceptions

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo

Say I have a bunch of queries that I am running in a consecutive order using PHP/MySQL PDO.  So ideally I start by BeginTransaction and finish by a commit.

Now, assume that one of the queries threw an exception in the middle of the run before the commit. Do I have to roll back when I catch the exception to handle it? Or just ignore assuming it will roll back automatically because the commit call is not made?

Thanks.

Comment: The queries do not include any create table. Those queries are onlyd deleting and updating entires in tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling the rollback function in the catch block if you want to be sure.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php

Comment: According to the docs (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), when you call beginTransaction, autocommit is turned off so that if the code ends before commit is called, it will not execute the query.